# Preserving whitespaces in the original text

Tags: antlr, grammar

In Antlr4 grammar , I have a rule which looks like

```
a :
    b
    {
       System.out.println($b.text);
    }
  ;
```

In the output I observe that whitespaces are missing ..

Example
    Input : 
 `int a = 5 ;`
    Output:
`inta=5;`

In grammar I also have a rule

```
ws: [ \t\n] -> skip;
```

How can I preserve white spaces?
(Grammar is big .. so I cant share it here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself ..In case someone needs ,

just replace

```
ws: [ \t\n] -> skip;
```

with

```
ws: [ \t\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

edit : Not sure whether this works in older antlr versions .. It surely works in Antlr4

Comment: yep, that saves my day. see also https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md